# hibernate 4 difference between xml and java config dialect

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-bean

I have a hibernate project and I am trying to configure it with xml and annotations, but

When I write

```
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="database" value="INFORMIX" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="mypackage.MyInformixDialect" />
</bean>
```

It works ok, but if I write:

```
@Bean
public HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter h = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    h.setDatabase(Database.INFORMIX);
    h.setDatabasePlatform("mypackage.MyInformixDialect");
    return h;
}
```

It says that

```
Unable to resolve name mypackage.MyInformixDialect as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
```

Why?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't answer why it won't work, but you can use ```h.setJpaPropertyMap()``` to specify the property ```hibernate.dialect``` which should be enough for your situation.

Comment: Could you provide full stacktrace, please.

Comment: The stacktrace is in the initial question, thanks

Comment: @dambros, thanks, I will try and let you know. Thank you